# jquery fullcalendar opening multiple calendars

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have just started to use jQuery fullcalendar http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ and I am experiencing a strange problem. I am launching the calendar from a click function and the first time I open the calendar it is fine and opening 1 calendar. However, if I click again, it adds 1 and I now have 2 calendars. This happens on each time I click it adds 1 calendar each time. Is there some option I have to add to reinitialize the calendar. The only option I could see was the  'render' option, but cannot work out how to use it. Thanks

**UPDATE**: New code Update

```
$(function() {
    $('#calhead1').on("click", function(){

        $("#msgcontent, #msgcontent2, #main, #msgtest").hide(1000);
        $("#cal").show();
    });
});
    // Start Calendar Script //

    $(function() {

            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();

            $('#cal').fullCalendar({

                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                },
                editable: true,
                theme: true,
                width: 760,
                height: 470,
                events: [
                    {
                        title: 'All Day Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Long Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
                    },
                    {
                        id: 999,
                        title: 'Repeating Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        id: 999,
                        title: 'Repeating Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Meeting',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Lunch',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Birthday Party',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Click for Google',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                        end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                        url: 'http://google.com/'
                    }
                ]
            });

            });

    // End Calendar Script //
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the `fullCalendar` function is designed to create a new calendar so your script is doing exactly what it's supposed to. You just need move that function outside your click event handler.

I'd also recommend moving from `live` to the new `on` method as jQuery has now deprecated `live`.

Your new code would look like:

```
$(function() {

    $('#cal').fullCalendar({

        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        theme: true,
        width: 760,
        height: 470,
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, 1)
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                url: 'http://google.com/'
            }
        ]
    });
    $('#calhead1').on("click", function(){

                    $("#msgcontent, #msgcontent2, #main, #msgtest").hide(1000);
                    $("#cal").show();
                    var date = new Date();
                    var d = date.getDate();
                    var m = date.getMonth();
                    var y = date.getFullYear();
    });

});
```

Comment: What happens now is when the calendar is first initialized, all that is visible is the header. I have to click today to see full calendar.

Comment: This looks correct but the d, m and y variables need to be declared before the calendar is initialised. Move them outside the click event and before you call $('#cal').fullCalendar({...

Comment: If you look at my updated code, that is the way it is at the moment. How do I need to update this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. jQuery live-function is deprecated, use .on()
2. Initialize your calendar outside of the click-event and just show and hide it on click.